# Resize UICollectionView and its sub views in IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am developing an IOS in which i am required to show the images in `GridView`. For this have used `UICollectionView` and images are also getting displayed in Grid.

I have used `SWRevealViewController` to implement `Sidebar Navigation`.

What i want to do is that when the `SideBar` is opened `UICollectionView` and its `Cells` to resize as shown in the image.
[image]

[image]
What i have already done is

The above images are from the same app built in `Android`.

Below are the images what i have done for `IOS` App.
[image]
[image]

If anybody can help to acheive the same would be a great help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i also faced same problem.....please help me...

Answer (score 0):

when you are tapping the button call this

```
[self.collectionView performBatchUpdates:nil completion:nil];
```

it will will invalidate the layout and resize the cells with animation (you can just pass nil to both block params if you've no extra adjustments to perform).

and then

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    // Adjust cell size for the mode slider opened or closed
    if (isSliderOpened) {
        return CGSizeMake(100.f, 100.f);
    }
    return CGSizeMake(200.f, 200.f);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i have already tried this but using above the number of columns increases i.e from 2 to 3. I want only two items per row for visibility point of view.